# 2 app icons after installing the release apk,using gradle build

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using `./gradlew assembleRelease` command to generate release apk for the app.On installing the app I am getting 2 icons of app.No clue what am I missing.No luch on google.
On clicking the second icon it just shows Simple Indeterminate.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.0.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'



defaultConfig {
    versionCode 23
    versionName "1.1.8.5"
    applicationId "com.squad.run"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 20
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}


signingConfigs {
    //Set debug.keystore file here
    release {
        def propsFile = rootProject.file('keystore.properties')
        def Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
        storeFile = file(props['storeFile'])
        storePassword = props['storePassword']
        keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
        keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false

    }

    release {
        zipAlign true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')

    }

}
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile project(':Libraries:viewPagerIndicator_Squadrun')
compile project(':Libraries:facebookSDK')
compile project(':Libraries:library')
compile project(':Libraries:progressHUD_Squadrun')
compile project(':Libraries:slidingMenuLibrary_SquadRun')
compile project(':Libraries:MobihelpSDK')
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.1'
compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.1.0.jar')
compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What is the "app list"? Do you mean the home screen launcher? Do you mean the list of installed applications in Settings? Do you mean something else? Beyond that, please consider updating your question to post your `build.gradle` file (from the app module) and your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Your manifest is declaring 2 launcher intents.

Comment: @Simon: Not necessarily -- the Gradle files might have separate `applicationId` values for `debug` versus `release` builds. In that case, having two launcher entries could mean that both the debug and the release apps were installed at the same time. In that case, there would be two entries in the list of installed applications, rather than just one (for an app with two `LAUNCHER` activities). That is why we need more information from the OP about the precise nature of the symptoms.

Comment: Checked my manifest file.it is not declaring 2 launcher manifests.It was working fine with eclipse.I have just made a switch to gradle build.

Comment: @Simon:On installing the release apk I am getting 2 icons.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My top guess is that there is more than one `LAUNCHER` activity, and that one of them is declared in a library project. Eclipse didn't merge the manifests, but Gradle does.

So, I would suggest you search for `android.intent.action.MAIN` in all `AndroidManifest.xml` files.

Comment: Sometimes we just include some other libraries with `android.intent.action.MAIN` declared inside. Need to re-check.