# User Complained About Double Icons on Download From Playstore

Tags: android

Some of my users complained that they get 2 icons of the same game on their android phones (screenshot attached).

I have made the game using unity and published its apk through unity as well before releasing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWStK.png) on playstore.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 app icons after installing the release apk,using gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957418/2-app-icons-after-installing-the-release-apk-using-gradle-build)

Comment: Check your LAUNCHER in Manifest file. if LAUNCHER add two time it show two icon in device.